# Find the complexification of a Lie Algebra

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to find the complexification of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$.
What I know about complexification is pretty much in Hall's book, Lie groups, Lie algebras and Representations (page 65).

Here is given the definition of the complexification $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ of a real vector space V, as the space of linear combinations $v_1 + iv_2$ with $v_1$, $v_2$ in V. Where we can consider this space over a real or complex field in the natural way:
$$\lambda(v_1 + iv_2)=\lambda v_1 + i \lambda v_2 \hspace{1cm} \lambda  \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$i(v_1 + iv_2)=-v_2+iv_1$$

Considered this, when I have to calculate the complexification of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$, I'd say I should distinguish the case of real or complex field.

Given the base of the space:
$$\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})=<T_1, T_2, T_3>$$
$\hspace{4cm}$
$T_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}
$
$\hspace{1cm}$
$T_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$
$\hspace{1cm}$
$T_3=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$

I'd say that the complexification over the real field is given by
$$\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})_{\mathbb{C}}=<T_1, T_2, T_3,iT_1, iT_2, iT_3>$$
and so over the real field $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})_{\mathbb{C}}=\mathfrak{sl},(2,\mathbb{C})$.
But in the case of the complexification over $\mathbb{C}$ I can't find a solution as $T_j$ and $iT_j$ are not anymore linear indipendent, so the base it seems to be given just by ${T_1, T_2, T_3}$, hence $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})_{\mathbb{C}}=\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ over $\mathbb{C}$, but I am quite sure this is wrong. In the end my problem is that I can't say what $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})_{\mathbb{C}}$ over the complex field is.
Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: What do you mean by complexification over $\mathbb{C}$? Complexification can only be done to real vector spaces.

Comment: for what I have understood (I can be completely wrong), I consider the complexification of real space as the space that comes out allowing the multplication by i. Then I can consider this new space  over a real or complex field, and so I can consider to multiply the elements of the complexified vector space by real or complex numbers. With over $\mathbb{C}$ I meant that I am considering the possibility of multiplying the elements of the complexification by complex numbers.

Comment: Aha, now I understand what you mean. Yes, it is now generated by $T_1,T_2,T_3$. But these are *complex* variables, not real ones any more, i.e., they span a complex vector space. So you get $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ again.

Comment: @DavidCraven I was wondering if it would make sense defining the complexification of any $A$-module $M$ by taking its tensor product with $\Bbb{C}$, i.e. $M^\Bbb{C}:=M\otimes_A \Bbb{C}$

Comment: If $A$ is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$, but unless $A=\mathbb{R}$ it would be infinite-dimensional in general, no?

Comment: I see I was creating too much problems for mysel, thanks for the help @David Craven

Comment: @DavidCraven: No. For any field extension $L \vert K$, if $M$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $K$, then $L \otimes_K M$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $L$. In particular, if you have say a 17-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ over $\mathbb Q$, the complexification $\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathfrak g$ is 17-dimensional as a complex vector space. -- Maybe you're thinking of scalar restriction, where indeed the dimension of say an $L$-vector space $M$, when viewed as $K$-v.s., is $[L:K] \cdot dim_L(M)$, in particular $=\infty$ if $[L:K]$ is infinite.

Comment: Sure, I was thinking infinite-dimensional over its original base ring. This is simply extension of scalars and is done all the time.

Comment: A word of caution, if one plans on going and complexifying everything willy nilly. If you do it with $A$ a field, great. If $A$ is a ring, like $\mathbb{Z}$, then modules that are not free over $\mathbb{Z}$, for example, finite abelian groups, are sent to zero by tensoring over an overfield of $\mathbb{Q}$.